# Items of list don't appear

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I have a list on Sharepoint Online, where i have a lot os items and it shows the number of items i have:
[image]

The problem is, when i enter in the list it says that the list is empty:
[image]

Can someone help me understanding why isn't showing me the items of the list?

Comment: Check list items permissions. Lisi items can have unique permissions. And check view filters.

Comment: Do you have permission on List and list items? please check.

Comment: Yes, i have permissions on the list

Comment: Check permissions on list items level, not list level.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. You have permissions on list level, but don't have permissions on list items level.
2. Default view may have filters based on column values. For example [Created]=Me
3. List settings option "Read items that were created by the user" is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no filter on the view.

Navigate to list->List settings->Advanced settings->don't choose "Read items that were created by the user".

Besides, make sure the items are published as major version.